# How to select element correctly in css

Tags: css

I would like to describe like attached image.

[image]

I set css selector,but seems it didn't work.

Why the selector didn't work well?

And How can I fix it?

Thanks.

```css
td {
height:50px;
width:50px;
border:solid black 1px;
cursor:pointer;
background-color:aqua;}

.test{
border-radius:50%;
background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="test"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any specified `height` and `width` to your `div.test` which is why its not showing. You might need to play with the dimensions since you'll be adding a border to it which will offset it slightly inside of your square.

```css
td {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  border:solid black 1px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:aqua;
}

.test {
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="test"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add these extra two properties in `.test` in `css`.

```
.test {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `display`, `height` and `width`. If you change your `.test` css class to:

```
.test {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    td {
        background-color: aqua;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .test {
        background: yellow;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```